# Ubuntu store Doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-store

I can't see any icons of the apps. Some categories like science or health seem not to have anything inside. What is going on? what should i do?

Comment: After clicking on the icon in the dash wait about 2 mins do they appear?

Comment: Please start by telling us your Ubuntu version and general setup. Did it work before?

Comment: "like science or health" suggests to me that you are referring to v21.10 which is not surprising since the repo's may not yet have been populated with apps for this version (21.10 only just released) Earlier versions had "Education & Science" which provides the clue.

Answer (score 0):

> Some categories like science or health

This suggests to me that you are using v21.10 which has only just been released from Beta (14th October) and some of the repos may not have been fully populated yet with updated apps for this version.

The clue lies in the earlier versions which list `Education & Science` rather than `Health and Fitness` and `Science` as the Categories featured in v21.10.

In the meantime, there may be little more that can be done until the repos begin to fill up with the apps you wish to choose or maybe chase developers to see what progress is being made on updating those apps you have an interest in.